# e2 studio undefined reference to 'posix_memalign'

Tags: eclipse, renesas

I need some help to solve this error. I am new to use **e2 studio** of Renesas. I started to import and build a project, which used for GR-Peach board. Then I got this error:

[image: error log : undefined reference to 'posix_memalign']

My toolchain version is **8.3.1.20190703**.
And the file definition is **stdlib.h** in directory *C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\8 2019-q3-update\arm-none-eabi\include*

```c
#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200112
int posix_memalign (void **, size_t, size_t) __nonnull((1))
        __result_use_check;
#endif
```

I also tried changing **-std=gnu99** and using **aligned_alloc** instead for posix_memalign but they not worked.

```c
// definition in stdlib.h
/*
 * If we're in a mode greater than C99, expose C11 functions.
 */
#if __ISO_C_VISIBLE >= 2011
void *  aligned_alloc(size_t, size_t) __malloc_like __alloc_align(1)
        __alloc_size(2) __result_use_check;
int at_quick_exit(void (*)(void));
_Noreturn void
    quick_exit(int);
#endif /* __ISO_C_VISIBLE >= 2011 */
```

Comment: If possible, it is better to include the error as text, rather than a screenshot, as text is searchable

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATE]**
The error log as below

```
'Building target: USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH.elf'
'Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Linker'
arm-none-eabi-g++ @"USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH.elf.in"
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./USBHost_custom_Addiso/USBisochronous/USBIsochronous.o: in function `HCITD::operator new(unsigned int, int)':
C:\Users\HoangSHC\e2_studio\workspace\USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH\Debug/../USBHost_custom_Addiso/USBisochronous/USBIsochronous.h:41: undefined reference to `posix_memalign'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\HoangSHC\e2_studio\workspace\USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH\Debug/../USBHost_custom_Addiso/USBisochronous/USBIsochronous.h:42: undefined reference to `posix_memalign'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./USBHost_custom_Addiso/USBisochronous/USBIsochronous.o: in function `_HCED::operator new(unsigned int)':
C:\Users\HoangSHC\e2_studio\workspace\USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH\Debug/../USBHost_custom_Addiso/USBisochronous/USBIsochronous.h:99: undefined reference to `posix_memalign'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH.elf] Error 1
makefile:125: recipe for target 'USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH.elf' failed
```

**[SOLVE]**
Origin source code

```c
        void* p;
        if (posix_memalign(&p, 256, size) == 0) {
            return p;
        }
        return NULL;
```

Replace to **memalign**

```c
        void* p;
        p = memalign(256, size);
        return p;
```

For details

```c
    inline void* operator new(size_t size) {
        void* p;
#if !defined (__CC_ARM) && (!defined (_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L))
        p = memalign(256, size);
        return p;
#else
        if (posix_memalign(&p, 256, size) == 0) {
            return p;
        }
        return NULL;
#endif
    }
```

After changing, I got this error: **undefined reference to `__wrap__memalign_r'**

```
'Building target: USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH.elf'
'Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Linker'
arm-none-eabi-g++ @"USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH.elf.in"
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7+fp/hard\libc.a(lib_a-malign.o): in function `memalign':
malign.c:(.text.memalign+0xe): undefined reference to `__wrap__memalign_r'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH.elf] Error 1
makefile:125: recipe for target 'USBHostC270_example_GR-PEACH.elf' failed
```

Then followed this

- https://os.mbed.com/questions/82888/Exporting-problem-with-SW4STM32/

to solve the problem.

For E2 Studio right click to project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross ARM C++ Linker > Miscellaneous > Linker flags (-Xlinker [option])

**Linker flags (-Xlinker [option])**

```
--wrap=_malloc_r
--wrap=_free_r
--wrap=_realloc_r
--wrap=_memalign_r
--wrap=_calloc_r
```

adding '_' symbol before the flags

```
--wrap=__malloc_r
--wrap=__free_r
--wrap=__realloc_r
--wrap=__memalign_r
--wrap=__calloc_r
```

**[RESEARCH]**

After comparing **stdlib.h** between older version 4.9 (`4.9 2015q3`) and current version 8 (`8 2019-q3-update`). I thought that `posix_memalign` maybe not supported anymore

In version **8**

`arm-none-eabi/include/stdlib.h` (not support posix_memalign)

```c
#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200112
int posix_memalign (void **, size_t, size_t) __nonnull((1))
        __result_use_check;
#endif
```

`arm-none-eabi/include/sys/features.h`

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE     200809L
```

In version **4.9**

`arm-none-eabi/include/stdlib.h` (support posix_memalign)

```c
#ifdef __rtems__
int _EXFUN(posix_memalign,(void **, size_t, size_t));
#endif
```

The GNU page says

> 9.637 posix_memalign
>
> Gnulib module: —
>
> Portability problems not fixed by Gnulib:
>
> This function is missing on some platforms: Mac OS X 10.5, FreeBSD 6.0, NetBSD 3.0, OpenBSD 3.8, Minix 3.1.8, AIX 5.1, HP-UX 11, IRIX 6.5, OSF/1 5.1, Solaris 10, Cygwin 1.5.x, mingw, MSVC 14, Interix 3.5, BeOS, Android 4.1.

Read more in

- https://patches-gcc.linaro.org/patch/11175/
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87683
- https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign
- http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/posix_005fmemalign.html